# Background task in mobile phone to access a secure element and a web server

Tags: mobile, background, task, apdu

Is it possible in a GSM mobile phone OS (e.g. Android, Win Mo, Symbian, etc.) to have some kind of background task or application able to exchange data at the same time with a web server and a secure element of the mobile?

The purpose if for the web server to be able to push APDUs to the secure element (an retrieve response APDUs) without activating the IHM of the mobile.

NB: I know that this is possible when the secure element is the one managing the GSM baseband, for example using BIP as described in [Ulysse](http://ulysse.pole-tes.com/) specifications. My question is only when using another secure element (e.g. Java Card in a microSD).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I used the French acronym "IHM" in place of "MMI" (man-machine interface).